# IR camera sensor data?

Tags: google-glass

Is there any way to grab the data from the interior IR camera?  I recall seeing on a previous XE patch a lab feature called gaze_on_mic that was since removed, which was speculated to use that.  Or otherwise, any way to grab the data?  And what exactly does it measure / when is it used currently?  Thanks.